# Cannot connect to SQLExpress

Tags: database, sql-server, c#

My C# app has problems connecting to my `SQLServerExpress` instance.

Running the app using `localhost\SQLExpress` or `<servername>\SQLExpress` in my connection string works locally on the server but not from other hosts in the network.

- I've already added a firewall rule for port `1433`.
- `AllowRemoteConnection` is set to `true`.

I still get an `SqlException` saying:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Is there anything else I need to check ?

**Update #1:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Process -Name sqlservr 
                        | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID 
                        | ForEach-Object {Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_ -state LISTEN 
                        | select LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State}


LocalAddress  : ::
LocalPort     : 58956
RemoteAddress : ::
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen

LocalAddress  : ::
LocalPort     : 1433
RemoteAddress : ::
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen

LocalAddress  : 0.0.0.0
LocalPort     : 58956
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen

LocalAddress  : 0.0.0.0
LocalPort     : 1433
RemoteAddress : 0.0.0.0
RemotePort    : 0
State         : Listen
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions should be written in English which includes error messages.

Comment: @Ramhound imo it's still more than clear what my problem is. but for your sake of heart i googled the translated message

Comment: It wasn't for "my sake of heart", questions here at Superuser, are expected to be in English.  The error indicates the server is not reachable.  This sounds like a pure programming issue which would be out of scope here at Superuser (which is the close reason I selected).

Comment: @Ramhound the question itself is written in english.. however the question itself should be good now. I choose SU over SO because is is working on the server itself (as written in the question) so the code is **fine** ! It has to be some sort of configuration mistake - I guess SU is the correct one for that (or am I wrong ?)

Comment: Can you add to the question the output of the following Powershell command from the "server":
`Get-Process -Name sqlservr | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ID | ForEach-Object {Get-NetTCPConnection -OwningProcess $_ -state LISTEN | select LocalAddress, LocalPort, RemoteAddress, RemotePort, State}`

Comment: @FelixD. - I don't know what to say, there are only two reasons you would get this error, the connection string is incorrect and/or your server is unreachable (which would be a configuration issue).  However, you indicated you performed the required configuration on the server, so that leaves the client performing the connection to the server.

Comment: @HelpingHand I ran the script u suggested. Everything looks fine ;(

Comment: Please try the `ping` and `telnet` test as per here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4828/verify-connectivity-to-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to SQL server configuration Manager (Win+R => SQLServerManager10.msc or SQLServerManager.msc)
2. Click SQL Network Services and navigate to concerned Server.
3. Enable TCP/IP Protocol for IP Based Conn (or) Named pipes for named connections(using server name)
4. Restart the SQL Server and Check